# What is the time complexity of this algorithm (uVa Online Judge 483 - Word Scrammble)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to improve my understanding of time complexity analysis. Here is the problem that I solved:

uVa Online Judge
483 - Word Scramble

Write a program that will reverse the letters in each of a sequence of words while preserving the order of the words themselves. The input file will consist of several lines of several words. Words are contiguous stretches of printable characters delimited by white space. The output will consist of the same lines and words as the input file. However, the letters within each word must be reversed.

Sample Input

I love you.
You love me.
We're a happy family.

Sample Output

I evol .uoy
uoY evol .em
er'eW a yppah .ylimaf

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 char  ch;
 stack<char> word;

  while (cin.get(ch)) {
    if (!isspace(ch)) {
      word.push(ch);
    } else {
      while (!word.empty()) {
        cout << word.top(); 
        word.pop();
      }
      cout << ch;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I think it is Big O(n), where n is the total amount of characters. For some reason I get confused when there are nested loops. My line of thinking is to look at the input size, and calculate each operation that is being done to it. The worst case for all operations would be O(n) (the push operation for the stack). Does that sound right?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the purpose of such OJ sites to grasp the solution yourself by researching, instead of cheating and asking for answers here?

Comment: I am not asking if my solution is correct. I am asking for help in analyzing the time complexity of the algorithm. This is distinctly different from the purpose of OJ sites. This is a forum to ask for help, and that's what I am doing.

Comment: _"This is a forum to ask for help"_ Nope, sorry! You're seemingly to completely miss, what the SO site is about. It's 1. Not a forum. 2. Not your personal helpdesk. 3. Meant to be a FAQ like Q&A site (where the questions and answers are useful for researchers about a particular programming topic from a long term view). 4. You might want to take [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again, or read [What topics I can ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to prove what I'm saying.

Comment: Well, if I made a mistake that wasn't my intention. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is O(n) if the total number of characters is `n`. The complexity is mainly affected by the loops such as `for` and `while` as that is where your multiple iterations lie.

You could also interpret the time complexity in another manner. It could be called O(m*n) where `n` is the number of words and `m` is the number of characters in each word.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking O(m*n) as well for the same reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases - the character is a space or it is not. If the character is space it gets directly printed(thus one operation). Otherwise the character is added to a stack and later on is popped from that stack exactly once(when a space char is met). Thus you perform at most two operations per character - a push and a pop. This overall you perform at most `2 * n` operations which means `O(n)`.